# Creating output based on multiple criteria

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames for 2 stacks that gives information about potential emission. One data frame gives the time frame of what hours the system turn on and off for 4 seasons. Each season start on specific date. The 2nd file give me the details of the stack.

I am trying with some sample file to test how to do this and so far I have managed to create a function following stack overflow example that allow me to create a data frame with the dates that I would like and a column with seasons for each date. I am really struggling now with the programming concept to understand how do I combine the 3 data frames to create the output template that I am trying to set up.

To show you an example my sample input are:

Stack_info File:

[image]

example seasonal Profile that shows when the system is on or off:

[image]

and the output I am after should create data frames for each year in the following format (only the black font and the red text to just explain what the values are):

[image]

What is the most difficult I am finding is that my output files for each year will have a unique first Row and the 2nd row will repeat for each pollutant. and from 3rd row the hourly data for all 8760 hours. This need to repeat for the next pollutant.

So far I have managed to create a function that helps me to assign season to each day of the year. For example:

```
#function to create seasons
d = function(month_day) which(lut$month_day == month_day)
lut = data.frame(all_dates = as.POSIXct("2012-1-1") + ((0:365) * 3600 * 24),
                 season = NA)
lut = within(lut, { month_day = strftime(all_dates, "%b-%d") })
lut[c(d("Jan-01"):d("Mar-15"), d("Nov-08"):d("Dec-31")), "season"] = "winter"
lut[c(d("Mar-16"):d("Apr-30")), "season"] = "spring"
lut[c(d("May-01"):d("Sep-27")), "season"] = "summer"
lut[c(d("Sep-28"):d("Nov-07")), "season"] = "autumn"
rownames(lut) = lut$month_day

## create date data frame and assign seasons
dates = data.frame(dates =seq(as.Date('2010-01-01'),as.Date('2012-12-31'),by = 1))

 dates = within(dates, { 
  season =  lut[strftime(dates, "%b-%d"), "season"] 
})
```

This gives me a dates data frame and my other 2 samples data frames are (as shown in the image):

```
structure(list(`Source no` = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Source = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Stack 1", "Stack 2"), class = "factor"), 
    Period = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Day = structure(c(2L, 
    6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 
    7L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", 
    "Thu", "Tue", "Wed"), class = "factor"), `Spring On` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), `Spring Off` = c(23L, 23L, 
    23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L), `Summer On` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "off", class = "factor"), `Summer Off` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "off", class = "factor"), `Autumn On` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "off", class = "factor"), `Autumn Off` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "off", class = "factor"), `Winter On` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "off"), class = "factor"), 
    `Winter Off` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("23", 
    "off"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Source no", "Source", 
"Period", "Day", "Spring On", "Spring Off", "Summer On", "Summer Off", 
"Autumn On", "Autumn Off", "Winter On", "Winter Off"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L)) -> profile

structure(list(SNAME = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Stack 1", "Stack 2"
), class = "factor"), ISVARY = c(1L, 4L), VELVOL = c(1L, 4L), 
    TEMPDENS = c(0L, 2L), `DUM 1` = c(999L, 999L), `DUM 2` = c(999L, 
    999L), NPOL = c(2L, 2L), `EXIT VEL` = c(26.2, 22.4), TEMP = c(341L, 
    328L), `STACK DIAM` = c(1.5, 2.5), W = c(0L, 15L), Nox = c(39, 
    33.3), Sox = c(15.5, 17.9)), .Names = c("SNAME", "ISVARY", 
"VELVOL", "TEMPDENS", "DUM 1", "DUM 2", "NPOL", "EXIT VEL", "TEMP", 
"STACK DIAM", "W", "Nox", "Sox"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L)) -> stack_info
```

If anyone could give me any guidance of how I can proceed with the programming part would be really useful as I am just not sure how I can approach this to create separate output files as data frame for year 2010, 2011 and 2012.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots and the sample data. One thing still isn't clear: how are the dates related to the other data sets? Is each `Period` in the `profiles` data frame supposed to be a date?

Comment: Hi thanks. the profile data set just gives the typical week timetable when the system come on and off. if you notice the Stack 1 only comes on ones so its only one set of weekly data. But the Stack 2 come on twice in spring time so there are two weeks data just shows when they are on and off for a typical week.  So it is like the excel if statement if the hour of the day is within that time frame and within that season then the switch is on so the pollutant column will show value, else the output still show  the hour with all other values accept the last 2 columns for pollutant would show 0.

Comment: Just to clarify the profile and stack_info data frame  gives the typical weekly profile and information about stack which i need to use to build up the emission template for each hour as shows in my output for any given years.

Comment: So the schedule is the same every year?

Comment: Yes it is same for every year. thanks

Comment: So your goal is to write some kind of function that allows you to input a year, and then outputs this table with the year automatically filled in, and the seasons correctly aligned?

Comment: Yes that is what ultimately I am trying to do but the programming bit of the function I am struggling to get my head around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your data is organised isn't ideal for processing. Maybe you have a look  at Hadley Wickhams papar about [tidy data](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjABahUKEwjV1-nro_nHAhVLWhoKHVqjAXk&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2Ftidyr%2Fvignettes%2Ftidy-data.html&usg=AFQjCNH2rlmHAbWzYglrvJNhrJGbM32Zsg).

According to your desired output you need a dataframe with the number of lines equal to the number of hours a specific machine (stack n) is switched on. Therefore I suggest you create a dataframe containing every hour of a given year:

```
d.out = data.frame(dates = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2010-01-01"), by=3600, to= as.POSIXct("2010-12-31")))
d.out$year = as.numeric(format(d.out$dates, "%Y"))
d.out$month = as.numeric(format(d.out$dates, "%m"))
d.out$day = as.numeric(format(d.out$dates, "%d"))
d.out$hour = as.numeric(format(d.out$dates, "%H"))
d.out$weekday = as.character(format(d.out$dates, "%a"))
d.out$doj = as.numeric(format(d.out$dates, "%j"))
d.out$season = "Winter"
d.out$season[d.out$doj >= 75 & d.out$doj < 121] = "Spring"
d.out$season[d.out$doj >= 121 & d.out$doj < 271] = "Summer"
d.out$season[d.out$doj >= 271 & d.out$doj < 312] = "Autumn"
```

The goal is to join this dataframe with your profile dataframe. Before joining, the profile-df has to be rearranged:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

profile_new =
profile %>%
    gather(season, hour, -c(`Source no`, Source, Period, Day)) %>%
    extract(season, c("season", "status"), "(\\w+?)\\s(\\w+)") %>%
    filter(hour != "off") %>%
    mutate(Day = as.character(Day), hour=as.numeric(hour)) %>%
    spread(status, hour)
```

Now it's easy to join the three dataframes to put together all the information you need to create your output:

```
d.out %>%
    inner_join(profile_new, by=c("weekday"="Day", "season"="season")) %>%
    group_by(Source, dates, year, day, weekday, season, hour) %>%
    summarise(status = any(hour >= On & hour <= Off)) %>%
    inner_join(stack_info, by=c("Source"="SNAME")) %>%
    mutate(Nox = ifelse(status, Nox, 0),
             Sox = ifelse(status, Sox, 0)) %>%
    arrange(Source, year, dates, hour) %>%
    select(Source, year, day, weekday, season, hour, `EXIT VEL`, TEMP, `STACK DIAM`, W, Nox, Sox)
```

Obviously it's not quite the format you posted. From here you could write your dataframe to a csv (stack by stack by using append = TRUE).

Comment: Thanks @MarkusN, could I just clarify one thing. When joining the three data frames I am missing some hours and not getting full 8760 hours. the idea is to get all 8760 hours of the years and those hours when the system is off will have all other columns filled in but the last 2 columns with pollutants will show 0, could you please advise how I can get the all 8760 hours?

Comment: After the join with profile you have multiple lines per stack and hour (because of multiple periods), therefore you have to group so that only one lines remains per stack and hour. Setting Nox/Sox to zero is a simple ifelse clause.

Comment: thanks it makes sense to me but the hours at the end I am loosing few hours as I was expecting to have all 8760 hours for each stack in the results but I get 8304 lines in total. So the hours I am looking is for total is 2 *8760 lines that is 17520 lines total. I realised I am missing the months when the switch was off.  I am wondering what I could b doing wrong ?

Comment: so from my data it looks like I am missing the seasons that the switch was off. I do also need to include those season and set the nox and sox to 0. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: if I take off  `filter(hour != "off") %>%` that gives me the missing seasons. when I run the remaining it gives me an error 'Error: incompatible types, expecting a numeric vector' and I think this is because it does not know how to handle the 'NA' for months when the switch is not on at all, could you give any advise on how I could address that so that all 8760 hours I can get for each stacks totalling 17520 lines for this example?

Comment: I figured that out. thank you so much for introducing me to dplyr package. its just totally awesome to what you can do with that :D really appreciate for taking your time to advise me with this :)